# Is there a simpler way of writing this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is there a way of writing this code in a simpler way? 
The code sample below uses jQuery obviously, just because it looks simple. I'm sure there must be a better way, as it repeats the contents of the functions.
The bit I'm confused by is how I'd pass the an id from the triggers into a single function.

Of course, I realise this could be done with javascript - any pointers on coding that would be greatly appreciated also.

Thanks

This is the HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carImage').hide();
  $('#triggerA').click(function(e) {
    $("#imageA").show();
    $("#imageB").hide();
    $("#imageC").hide();
    $("#imageD").hide();
  });
  $('#triggerB').click(function(e) {
    $("#imageA").hide();
    $("#imageB").show();
    $("#imageC").hide();
    $("#imageD").hide();
  });
  $('#triggerC').click(function(e) {
    $("#imageA").hide();
    $("#imageB").hide();
    $("#imageC").show();
    $("#imageD").hide();
  });
  $('#triggerD').click(function(e) {
    $("#imageA").hide();
    $("#imageB").hide();
    $("#imageC").hide();
    $("#imageD").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: #36F;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 75px;
  float: left;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: #F0C;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#selectors {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectors">
  <div class="item" id="triggerA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerC">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerD">
    D
  </div>
</div>

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/ff0" id="imageA" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f0f" id="imageB" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/0ff" id="imageC" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0" id="imageD" class="carImage" />
```

Comment: Uhm, you're already doing it with javascript ?

Comment: You can do all that with css only, just depends on the exact functionality you want.

Comment: You can select multiple items at once (e.g. $('#imageB, #imageC, #imageD').hide()) in your selectors

Comment: Like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yzeruyrp/1/**

Comment: use class instead ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and `class`es to simplify your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carImage').hide();
  $('.item').click(function() {
    $('.carImage').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
  })
});
```

```css
.item {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: #36F;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 75px;
  float: left;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: #F0C;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#selectors {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectors">
  <div class="item" id="triggerA">
    A
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerB">
    B
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerC">
    C
  </div>
  <div class="item" id="triggerD">
    D
  </div>
</div>

<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/ff0" id="imageA" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/f0f" id="imageB" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/0ff" id="imageC" class="carImage" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100/0f0" id="imageD" class="carImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Feature bar demo</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carImage').hide();
    $('.item').click(function(e) {
        $('.carImage').each(function(index, img) {
            img.style.display = (img.id.slice(-1) == e.target.id.slice(-1) ? 'inline-block' : 'none')
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
 .item {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:3em;
  padding:1em;
  margin:0.5em;
  background-color:#36F;
  color:#FFF;
  width:75px;
  float:left;
 }
 .item:hover {
  background-color:#F0C;
 }
 a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#FFF;
 }
 #selectors {
  overflow:auto;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="selectors">
        <div class="item" id="triggerA">
        A
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="triggerB">
        B
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="triggerC">
        C
        </div>
        <div class="item" id="triggerD">
        D
        </div>
    </div>
 
  <img src="cars1.jpg" id="imageA" class="carImage">
        <img src="cars2.jpg" id="imageB" class="carImage">
        <img src="cars3.jpg" id="imageC" class="carImage">
        <img src="cars4.jpg" id="imageD" class="carImage">

</body>
</html>
```